# Intel core 2 duo 2.4ghz vs Athlon X2 2.8ghz dual core?

Tags: cpu

I tried googling but I keep seeing different versions, I'm trying to buy a secondhand CPU and the last two choices I have differentiate in the processor.

Is intel core 2 duo 2.4ghz better than Athlon X2 2.8ghz dual core?

Comment: When comparing CPU performance, your first port of call should be the  [Passmark](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/) benchmarks. Also shopping requests are not permitted on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally find that the AMD system shows slightly lower memory latency and offers slightly better IO bandwidth.

Its all based on what you benchmark with?

The Intel CPU should be the faster for some multimedia work (more CPU intensive, & the code is more based around intel CPU's) whereas the AMD will be faster for things such as doing virus scans (more IO).

If you are looking for a gaming CPU I would go with the Intel, for more office based work I would go for AMD.

Comment: It's for photoshop+IDE+Browser+Wamp. Thanks! If I could just choose by color it would have been easier.

Comment: I would go with the Intel then :)

Comment: what if that intel compared to AMD Phenom X3 8550 Triple Core 2.2GHz?